# roslibjs - subscribe to topic with custom messages

Tags: ros

I want to access data published by a gps node in a custom gps msg via roslibjs.
I therefore used [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality), but the message object that's given back by the subscribe callback in my case is always just **undefined**.

```
  var listener = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/gps_raw',
    messageType : 'gps_node/gps_raw'
  });
  listener.subscribe(function(message) {
    console.log('Received message on ' + listener.name + ': ' + message.data);
  });
```

Result:

```
Received message on /gps_raw: undefined
```

MSG Structure:

```
int32 gps_sats
float32 lat
float32 lon
int32 heading
int32 alt
```

https://github.com/MrGrimod/ros_airdrop/blob/master/src/gps_node/msg/gps_raw.msg

Comment: Could you provide the structure of the `gps_raw` message?

Comment: I added it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message type does not have the field `data`. Try to display other fields in the console log: `gps_stats`, `lat`, `lon` etc.

edit: you can also use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to display all of the message's content, like this:

```
console.log(`Received message on  ${listener.name}: ${JSON.stringify(message)`);
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that .data would dump all the fields :D

Answer (score -1):

source your catkin_ws with your custom msg